# How to use transaction in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am using php/mysql. i know about the transaction in mysql but can't use in my script. below is my script how can i use php transaction in my code.i.e BEGIN, ROLLBACK, COMMIT

```
foreach($json_a['shop'] as $jsondata=>$json)
{
if($json['category']==='product')
{
$name_product=$json['name'];
$query1="insert into product(id,name,user_id)values('','" . mysql_real_escape_string($name_product). "','1')";

$result1=mysql_query($query1) or die("error in query".mysql_errno());
//echo "success...!";
$product++;
}
else
if($json['category']==='order')
{
$name_order=$json['name'];
$query2="insert into order(id,name,user_id)values('','" . mysql_real_escape_string($name_order). "','1')";

$result2=mysql_query($query2) or die("error in query".mysql_errno());
$order++;
}
else
if($json['category']==='sale')
{
$name_sale=$json['name'];
$query3="insert into sale(id,name,user_id)values('','" . mysql_real_escape_string($name_sale). "','1')";

$result3=mysql_query($query3) or die("error in query".mysql_errno());
$sale++;
}
}
```

Comment: You can use them by ... using them in the right places?  Can you clarify your question, please?  It's hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: i am asking about the transaction and the purpose of my question is sometimes first query is executed and data is inserted in database but the second query is not executed properly so i want to rollback the transaction so that the order of insertion is not disturbed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply issue `mysql_query('START TRANSACTION');` and check for errors at every one of your inserts. If one of them doesn't succeed issue a ROLLBACK immediately without doing any of the remaining queries. If everything goes fine with all of them issue a COMMIT.

It may be easier to put them in a try-catch block to avoid using too many levels of nesting with if-else.

```
// START TRANSACTION
try{
    // INSERT 1
    if(failed)
        throw new Exception();

    // INSERT 2
    if(failed)
        throw new Exception();

    // INSERT 3
    if(failed)
        throw new Exception();

    // COMMIT
}
catch(Exception $e){
    // ROLLBACK
}
```

You may also want to take a look into PHP's [PDO extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php). Transactions are part of its features.

Comment: +1 this is sexy, nice concise representation of how this should ideally be structured.

Comment: i nested the queries just because it is part of foreach loop look at my updated question.

Comment: @hunter You can use that strategy no mater what you have. Just wrap everything up with the `try` and when you've decided a ROLLBACK is mandated you throw an exception. Note that in your case it can't happen for two of the inserts to be executed in the same run, so transactions aren't really needed. Do you plan to add some other queries?

Comment: yeah, after collecting the three variables `product, order` and `sale` i want to insert these in user table after executing these three queries. so what should you recommend for me.

Comment: as you said that **so transactions aren't really needed** so in my case if query1 is inserted successfully and in second query there is some error than how could be able to rollback.

Comment: @hunter _so transactions aren't really needed_ scratch that. I wasn't paying enough attention. You clearly have multiple inserts. You need transactions. Do as I said, wrap the `foreach` in a try-catch block like in the mock-up from my answer. Remove all your `die`s and instead use `$result3 === false` to check if the query has failed and, if so, throw the exception. You may want to take a look in the manual if you're not familiar with how exceptions work.

Comment: the catch code should be `catch(Exception $e){` and not the other way around as above

Comment: @Sphinx Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use PDO. Example:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);

$db->beginTransaction();
$db->exec("delete from mytable");

$allGood = doSomethingElse();

if ($allGood)
{
  $db->commit();
} else {
  $db->rollBack();
}
```

or a more elegant method:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
$db->beginTransaction();

try{
  //first execution      
  $db->exec("delete from mytable");

  //second execution
  $db->exec("insert into anothertable");

  //if all went well
  $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {

  //something broke, hit undo
  $db->rollBack();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The same rules/syntax apply here as they do in regular MySQL statements regarding transactions.

Here's an example:

```
$query0 = 'START TRANSACTION;';
mysql_query($query0) or die('woops' . mysql_error());

/* all of your queries here */

$query5 = 'COMMIT;';
mysql_query($query5) or die('woops' . mysql_error());
```

More information on the MySQL syntax for transactions can be found here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html